# Infinite sum of nonnegative USC functions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence of real nonnegative functions on $\mathbb{R}^1$, and consider the following statement:

If each $f_n$ is upper semicontinuous (USC), then $\sum \limits_{1}^{\infty} f_n$ is USC.
Is this statement true or not?

**Proof:** Let $f_n=1_{(-\infty, -\frac{1}{n}]\cup [\frac{1}{n}, +\infty)}$. It's easy to see that $f_n$ is USC because it's a characteristic function of closed set and for any fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the sum $\sum \limits_{1}^{n}f_k$ is USC. Then $$\sum \limits_{1}^{\infty}f_k=\sup \limits_{n} \sum \limits_{1}^{n}f_k$$
I'll prove that this infinite sum is not USC function. Let's consider the following set: $$\left\{x: \sum \limits_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{x: \sup \limits_{n} \sum \limits_{1}^{n}f_k(x)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left\{x:  \sum \limits_{1}^{n}f_k(x)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}.$$ 
It's easy to check that $$\left\{x:  \sum \limits_{1}^{n}f_k(x)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\left\{x:  f_1(x)=\dots=f_n(x)=0\right\}=\bigcap _{k=1}^{n}\left\{x:  f_k(x)=0\right\}=$$$$\bigcap _{k=1}^{n}\left(-\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Hence
$$\left\{x: \sum \limits_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)=\{0\}$$

but the last set is NOT open in $\mathbb{R}^1$. So the above statement is false.

Is my counterexample correct? Would be very grateful for checking out!

Comment: Fine, _if_ you're allowing the value $+\infty$ for your sum. You could easily modify this example to get a finite-valued counterxample...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, It's not seems easily for me. Can you little bit expand your answer?

Comment: I'll agree and plus-1 David's comment that the counter-example can be modified, but the way I have in mind seems not so easy (not simply weighting those functions by decaying coefficients, but doing a bit more), perhaps David has an easier way.  PS: I was attracted to this question since I am from USC.  Haha.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, It would be very interesting if you'll post an answer for finite case.

Comment: Oops. It's not quite as simple as I was thinking, sorry.

Comment: @Michael What I had in mind is nonsense.I believe I see how to do it, but if your version is correct you got there before me. So go for it - I'll check back later...

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the discussion in the comments: Define

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 0\\ 
nx(1-x)^n  & x \in [0,1]\\ 0 & x >0\end{cases}$$

Then each $f_n$ is continuous and nonnegative on $\mathbb R.$ We easily get $\sum f_n(x) < \infty$ for all $x.$ Call the sum $f(x).$ Then $f(1/n) \ge f_n(1/n) = (1-1/n)^n \to 1/e.$ If follows that $f(0) = 0< 1/e\le \limsup_{x\to 0} f(x).$ This violates upper semicontinuity at $0.$

Comment: Looks good.  Another way (simpler than what I was originally thinking when I wrote the comment to David) is to 
paste together functions $g_n(x) = 1_{x \in [1/(n+1), 1/n]}$.  That is, consider  $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x)$.  These functions overlap so that $g(x) \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $g(x) = 2$ at points $x \in \{1/n\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Your example is easier actually. We could modify it a bit and let g_n be a triangle of height 1 over the base [1/(n+1),1/n]. Then sum g_n is continuous except at 0, where we have the same kind of behavior with the limsup.

Comment: Simpler yet: $f_n=\chi_{\{1/n\}}$.

Comment: True!$\,\,\,\,\,$